# Unable to run localhost in windows 10

Tags: apache-http-server, localhost, xampp

The status of my Apache is Green but when I access localhost it displays "unable to connect".

I already stopped www publishing service and still no luck.
I changed port 80 to 8080 in apache conf and still no luck.

How to fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you specify the port number as well like `localhost:8080/` ?

Comment: What is the output of `netstat -ab -p TCP` run in a command-prompt window that was opened as administrator?

Comment: Hi @pun yes I did but still, page cannot be viewed.

Comment: Hi @RedGrittyBrick the output is TCP 0.0.0.0:8080 and there's more on the list like DoSVC, EventLog, svchost.exe, etc.